# "defunct" vs. "deceased" vs. "departed"

Tags: word-choice

After reading some dictionaries I realized that these three words aren't perfectly interchangeable, even if I cannot exactly recognize their differences.

Specifically I don't understand whether "defunct" is used in reference to dead persons or not—it seems to be more appropriate in reference to abstract things ("a defunct argument", "a defunct story")—, and what the contexts are in which we should use "deceased" or "departed".

So, suppose I want to ask to a person if a their relative has died, how can I ask without being disrespectful?

> - Is/has your sister *defunct*?
> - Is/has your sister *deceased*?
> - Is/has your sister *departed*?

Answer (score 4):

Let's begin by confirming your first assumption: you're correct that *defunct* would not be used to refer to a person, though the [dictionary definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/defunct) might make you think otherwise:

> **de·funct**  adj.
>
> Having ceased to exist or live: *a defunct political organization*.

Though the definition sounds like it could describe a person, you'll note that the example sentence refers to a non-living entity, and I can't imagine native speakers using *defunct* to describe a person except in a satirical sense.

Now, as for *deceased* and *departed* (and your verb tenses). *Deceased* is definitely appropriate to be used with people. However it is a state of being, not an action, so you would say:

> Is your sister deceased?

What you're asking is *is your sister currently in the state of being deceased*. If you used *has* you would be saying *has your sister deceased recently?* and we don't talk like that; you could say *has your sister* ***died*** *recently*, but we don't use *deceased* as a verb like that.

[As an interesting aside, while we don't use *decease* in that manner, we do use *predecease* (meaning *to die before someone else* that way). For example, *Mary predeceased her older brothers, Jim and Harry.*]

Now, as for *departed*. Departed can be used in the context of people's deaths, but not in the sentence you've got there. If I heard:

> Has your sister departed?

I'd wonder if she'd left for the train station yet, and if I heard:

> Is your sister departed?

I'd have no idea what was meant.

The way we use *departed* in this frame of reference is in common phrases, such as *the dearly departed*. This has the clear meaning of *loved ones who have passed away* to native speakers.

However in conversation we tend to use euphemisms to avoid touchy subjects, so probably the most common and socially acceptable sentence would be:

> Has your sister passed away?

Comment: Well-said. The only time I'd apply _defunct_ to a deceased person would be if that person was a soul singer (i.e., _"James Brown, who was defunct in 2006..."_) – but that's a rare case, used only to form a pun (and some might say a rather tasteless one at that).

Answer (score 3):

None of these is really suitable for asking this delicate question.*

*Defunct*, as you say, is rarely used of persons.

*Deceased* is mostly legal or official. It is used as an attributive adjective or as a nominal, but rarely as a predicate adjective.

> I leave my library to JohnB, the son of my deceased uncle WilliamB.
>   According to the police, the deceased is a white male of middle age.

*Departed* is quite old-fashioned. It is used mostly as a nominal, and my impression is that it is mostly employed now at funerals, by the presiding minister.

The most common verb in US euphemistic speech today is probably *pass away* or in recent years simply *pass*. The participle is not used much, however, so you should say

> *Has* your sister passed away?

But in most circumstances I would think it more graceful to ask

> Is your sister still alive?

---

*I myself use *die* and *dead*, but I am notoriously crude.

Comment: 14 seconds? Really?? xP

Comment: @WendiKidd I think you win, because I edited. But I'm gonna leave it up 'cause we need to jack up the Q/A ratio.